# How do I determine the object that was liked by a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-stream-story

I'm doing a FQL query to get posts from a user:

```
{
  "feeds": "SELECT type, actor_id, target_id, app_data, action_links, permalink, post_id, viewer_id, created_time, updated_time, source_id, message, description, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'owner' AND source_id = <userId> AND is_hidden = 0 LIMIT 50"
}
```

For the most part, the results are great.  However, if the result contains a post about the user "liking" something, how can I determine what was "liked"?

For example:

```
{
      "type": null, 
      "actor_id": <userId>, 
      "target_id": null, 
      "app_data": [
      ], 
      "action_links": null, 
      "permalink": "", 
      "post_id": "<postId>", 
      "viewer_id": <userId>, 
      "created_time": 1369109320, 
      "updated_time": 1369109320, 
      "source_id": <userId>, 
      "message": "", 
      "description": "<user name> likes a status.", 
      "attachment": {
        "description": ""
      }
    }
```

Which status?

Or:

```
{
      "type": null, 
      "actor_id": <userId>, 
      "target_id": null, 
      "app_data": [
      ], 
      "action_links": null, 
      "permalink": "", 
      "post_id": "<postId>", 
      "viewer_id": <userId>, 
      "created_time": 1367029922, 
      "updated_time": 1367029922, 
      "source_id": <userId>, 
      "message": "", 
      "description": "<user name> likes a link.", 
      "attachment": {
        "description": ""
      }
    }
```

Which link?

Do I need to do a multi-part query to get the extra data from a different table?
Why is the target_id always null?

Comment: Have you actually retrieved any results that have a description of "<user name> likes a link."? or is this a hypothetical case you want to handle?

Comment: Those were pulled directly out of the FQL response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long standing bug, that hasn't been fixed for reasons unknown 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522743067756848

There is actually no efficient way to do it in the API.

`<postId> = <userid_pId>`

The way via Facebook UI would be https://www.facebook.com/userid/posts/pId

I've opened a new bug report but I highly doubt it will be fixed.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/648986871793611